# Detecting if there is data transfer in iOS app with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I was wanting to know if anyone knows how to detect if there is data transfer or not within an iOS app. I am using a Swift Reachability library to detect if there is wifi or cellular connection, but this does not let me know if there is actual data being transferred.

My app starts out with a WKWebView, and in the case there is no data being transferred to load the webview that takes up the entire screen, I would like to present an alertController to the user.

Reachability lets me know if there is a connection to wifi or a cellular network, but they don't help with letting me know if there is any data being transferred. I'm testing with my wifi on, but with no network connection, and I'm unable to present any alertController as connection is always passing true for isReachable().

Does anyone know how to go about this? Thank you.

Comment: If I am getting this right. You basically want to know the exact state of internet connection right ? This can be done via Alamofire if you are using alamofire for feteching resources.

Comment: I was looking into Alamofire because of this, but I'm not fetching any type of JSON, I'm loading up a webview. Is there a way for me to test to see if a website can be fetched with Alamofire, and if yes, then load the webview?

Comment: With alamofire you can simply check that Internet is available or not whether its Wifi or cellular network. I can post tge answer for this if you want

Comment: Yes, Umair, your help would be appreciated. This is what I have so far, but even when data is turned off, it's not calling out the code in the failing statusCode code block...

Comment: Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get").responseJSON { response in
        if let statusCode = response.response?.statusCode {
          if statusCode >= 400 && statusCode < 600 {
            (code here doesn't get called when no data connection exists)
          } else if statusCode >= 200 && statusCode < 400 {
            let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url!)
            self.webView.load(urlRequest)
          }
        }
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire Provide the functionaly to check the network status. So here it is in detail with some other functionality.

I have created  an APIClient Manager class in my project.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import AlamofireNetworkActivityIndicator

// Completion handeler
typealias TSAPIClientCompletionBlock = (response: NSHTTPURLResponse?, result: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void

// MARK: -

class TSAPIClient: Manager {

// MARK: - Properties methods

private let manager = NetworkReachabilityManager(host: "www.apple.com") // could be any website, Just to check connectivity

private var serviceURL: NSURL?

// MARK: - init & deinit methods

init(baseURL: NSURL,
     configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration(),
     delegate: SessionDelegate = SessionDelegate(),
     serverTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager? = nil) {
    super.init(configuration: configuration, delegate: delegate, serverTrustPolicyManager: serverTrustPolicyManager)

    var aURL = baseURL

    // Ensure terminal slash for baseURL path, so that NSURL relativeToURL works as expected

    if aURL.path?.characters.count > 0 && !aURL.absoluteString.hasSuffix("/") {
        aURL = baseURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("")
    }

    serviceURL = baseURL
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.sharedManager.isEnabled = true

    observeNetworkStatus()
}

// MARK: - Public methods

func serverRequest(methodName: String, parameters: [String : AnyObject]? , isPostRequest: Bool, headers: [String : String]?, completionBlock: TSAPIClientCompletionBlock) -> Request {

    let url = NSURL(string: methodName, relativeToURL: serviceURL)
    print("\(url)")

    let request = self.request(isPostRequest ? .POST : .GET, url!, parameters: parameters, encoding: isPostRequest ? .JSON : .URL, headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<600)
        .responseJSON { response in

            switch response.result {

            case .Success:
                completionBlock(response: response.response, result: response.result.value, error: nil
                )
                break

            case .Failure(let error):
                completionBlock(response: response.response, result: nil, error: error)
                break
            }
    }

    return request
}

func cancelAllRequests() {
    session.getAllTasksWithCompletionHandler { tasks in

        for task in tasks {
            task.cancel()
        }
    }
}

// this will contiously observe network changes 
func observeNetworkStatus() {

    manager?.listener = { status in
        print("Network Status Changed: \(status)")
        if status == .NotReachable {

        } else if status == .Unknown {

        } else {
            // status is reachable
            // posting a notification for network connectivity    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(kNetworkStatusConnectedNotification, object: nil)
        }

    }

    manager?.startListening()
}
// If you want to check network manually for Example before pushing a viewController.
func isNetworkReachable() -> Bool {
    return manager?.isReachable ?? false
  }
}
```

**kNetworkStatusConnectedNotification**  is a constant declared as following

```
let kNetworkStatusConnectedNotification = "kNetworkStatusConnectedNotification"
```

Now, Where you want to observe the network changes in your application, register the notification in that viewController as follows

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(HomeViewController.applicationIsConnectedToNetwok), name: kNetworkStatusConnectedNotification, object: nil)
```

and in the selector do whatever you want to do when you get network connectivity

```
func applicationIsConnectedToNetwok() {
// e.g LoadData 
}
```

I have written this method in my Session class and I am using it to check connectivity mannualy

```
func isNetworkReachable() -> Bool {
    return YourAPIClient.sharedClient.isNetworkReachable()
}
```

I have added some comments in the code for your understanding. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for sharing, Umair. I appreciate your time in helping me. So I've been reading over your code and trying to get a better understanding of how to go about checking the data connection, but I'm still a bit unsure as to how you would actually use this class within the code. Would you mind sharing how you would use this in a view controller?

Comment: Your code did help me work out how to fix my solution though :) Thank you for that, Umair!

Comment: You got it working  Please accept or upvote the answer if it helped you.?